# What is the form of Javascript used in this class declaration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This is from the [table example](http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/table) from React-toolbox (which could use a tag)

```
class TableTest extends React.Component {
  state = { selected: [], source: users };

  handleSelect = (selected) => {
    this.setState({selected});
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <Table
        model={UserModel}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
        selectable
        multiSelectable
        selected={this.state.selected}
        source={this.state.source}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

This does not compile with webpack/babel for me but the following 'correct' Javascript does.  Is this JSX notation and a sign that I'm not transpiling JSX as I think I am?

```
class TableTest extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { selected: [], source: users };

    this.handleSelect = (selected) => {
      this.setState({selected});
    };
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Table
        model={UserModel}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
        selectable
        multiSelectable
        selected={this.state.selected}
        source={this.state.source} />
    );
  }  
}
```

Webpack/babel chokes on:

```
ERROR in ./src/client/app/app.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (21:8)

  19 | 
  20 | class TableTest extends React.Component {
> 21 |   state = { selected: [], source: users };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using [class properties](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), which are currently part of Babel's [stage 2 preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/).

For this code, the `=` statements in the class body would get moved into the constructor by the class properties transform.

[Here's the original code in the Babel REPL with suitable presets applied](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=class%20TableTest%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20state%20%3D%20%7B%20selected%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20source%3A%20users%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20handleSelect%20%3D%20(selected)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7Bselected%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20render%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CTable%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20model%3D%7BUserModel%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onSelect%3D%7Bthis.handleSelect%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20selectable%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20multiSelectable%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20selected%3D%7Bthis.state.selected%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20source%3D%7Bthis.state.source%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D).

You will need to add this preset (or a lower stage preset, as all Babel stage presets also include higher stage features) to your Babel config, or add the transform plugin to it individually.

Example Babel config which would provide all the features you need to transpile the original code:

```
{
  presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2']
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I needed to install a stage preset (stage 0 seems standard but I don't know why and I suppose that's dangerous) and add it to .babelrc.

Comment: @bp.: The stage presets correspond to the [different stages in the process of proposing new JS language features](https://github.com/tc39/proposals). Stage 0 is brand new ideas, stage 4 is features that will for sure be included in the next version of JavaScript. Obviously a lot of early stage proposals will get abandoned or turned down, so that's the trade off - if you're on the stage 0 preset you get *everything*, but at the risk that some of the features you use might end up being non-standard in the future.

Answer (score -1):

It's throwing an error on the `=` declaration inside of the class. You need to bind `this` to `handleSelect` due to React's no autobinding rule.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding

```
class TableTest extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        selected: [], source: users
      };
      this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  }

  handleSelect(selected) {
    this.setState({selected});
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Table
        model={UserModel}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
        selectable
        multiSelectable
        selected={this.state.selected}
        source={this.state.source}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: chill @Quill I added one

Comment: My question was about why the first example didn't work and what notation it actually was.  I can _make_ it work with the correct example below but I wanted to understand what was going wrong.

Comment: @bp there's no more autobinding in es6 components. if you want to bind 'this' to the function, you need to do so in the constructer